# Como criar um gatilho no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tenho as tabelas `usuarios`, `usuario_voto`, e `classificacao_usuario`.

`Usuarios:` tabela de usuarios do sistema.

`usuario_voto:` tabela que armazena voto de um usuario em outro.

`classificacao_usuario:` tabela que armazena média de votos de um usuario.

**Funcionamento.**

Cada usuario possui uma tabela classificao_usuario, onde consta sua média de votos.

A tabela `usuario_voto` possui as colunas `usuario_votante`, `usuario_votado` e `nota` .

**Objetivo**

Quando um usuario votar em outro(inserir `usuario_voto`), quero que seja disparado um gatilho onde que após o voto, seja atualizada a coluna nota da tabela `classificao_usuario`. A trigger deve pegar a média de votos deste usuario que foi votado na tabela `usuario_voto`) .

Acho eu que o select do gatilho deve ficar mais o menos assim.

```
SELECT AVG(nota) FROM usuario_voto as v WHERE v.usuario_votado = <ID_DO_USUARIO_QUE_QUERO> group by v.usuario_votado
```

e o update acho eu que ficara mais o menos assim

```
UPDATE classificacao_usuario SET nota = <MEDIA> WHERE  id = <ID_DO_USUARIO_QUE_QUERO>
```

Answer (score 5):

Para isso tem de criar um Trigger que é activado depois de ser feito um `INSERT` na table `usuario_voto`.

### Exemplo de um trigger em MySQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ActualizaDados AFTER INSERT ON usuario_voto
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    -- Aqui dentro faz o UPDATE para actualizar os dados.
    UPDATE classificacao_usuario SET nota = <MEDIA> WHERE  id = <ID_DO_USUARIO_QUE_QUERO>
  END;
```

**Nota:** Este trigger só é executado apenas se o INSERT correr correctamente. Se ocorrer algum erro durante a execução do INSERT o trigger não será executado.

Answer (score 3):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER nomedoTrigger after INSERT ON usuario_voto
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Aqui você coloca a estrutura do trigger.
END //
delimiter ;
```

Acho que você deveria criar uma variável que pegue o valor da media de votos desse usuário e ai fazer o update.